XML serialisation for utf characters contains ncr for surrogate pair
I have a payload that may contain some text like . When I serialize this payload to xml, I expect such characters to be not encoded to ncr or encoded as &#134071; a single character but I observe &#55362;&#57271; two (surrogate) characters together representing one same unicode character.
A minimal example demonstrating this problem is:
package something...;

import net.shibboleth.utilities.java.support.xml.SerializeSupport;
import org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationException;
import org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService;
import org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.XSString;
import org.opensaml.core.xml.schema.impl.XSStringBuilder;
import org.opensaml.core.xml.util.XMLObjectSupport;
import org.opensaml.saml.saml2.core.Attribute;
import org.opensaml.saml.saml2.core.AttributeValue;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

/** Generates Response.xml using openSAML library version 3. */
final class SamlResponseGenerator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      InitializationService.initialize();
    } catch (InitializationException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

    // First Name Attribute.
    Attribute firstNameAttribute =
        (Attribute) XMLObjectSupport.buildXMLObject(Attribute.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
    firstNameAttribute.setName("FirstName");
    XSStringBuilder firstNameTestValueStringBuilder = new XSStringBuilder();
    XSString firstNameAttributeValueXS =
        firstNameTestValueStringBuilder.buildObject(
            AttributeValue.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME, XSString.TYPE_NAME);
    String myName = "";
    firstNameAttributeValueXS.setValue(myName);
    firstNameAttribute.getAttributeValues().add(firstNameAttributeValueXS);

    Document doc = XMLObjectSupport.marshall(firstNameAttribute).getOwnerDocument();
    String docString = SerializeSupport.nodeToString(doc);
    System.out.println(docString);
  }

  private SamlResponseGenerator() {}
}

List of solutions tried:

Transformers (Does not work)
XMLHelper.writeNode with a filewriter opened with utf-8 encoding format Does not work
Postprocess xml output (Works but this is hacky)
Tried with OpenSAML v2 and v3 (Does not work)
XML marshalling of surrogate pairs

Am I using an incorrect serializer or a incorrect config. What may I do to get the desired output (similar to legacy server).
Doesn't this wikipedia article suggests that surrogate pairs are not allowed in numeric character reference notation.

The output you are getting is totally incorrect, as you observe. I don't know your toolchain well enough to be able to see what component is at fault.

The serialize method and deserialize method have to be compatible.  There are no specification that covers serialize/deserialize from java to xml.  So you must use the same library/version to get proper results.  Your link says "Java strings have an interface with a bias towards UTF-16".  There is nothing wrong with serializing a 16 bit  character to two 8 bit characters as long as when you deserialize you get the correct 16 bit character.

but I observe �� two (surrogate) characters together representing one same unicode character. Are you sure that's not simply how that character is encoded in UTF-16? Looks like it to me

When I run your code, I get &#134071;

@jdweng My output is expected to go on wire and consumed by a variety of saml clients. I want to do due diligence to not break any of them. Some of these may fail to parse the xml. So I want to be compatible with as many as possible of them.

You are using OpenSaml which is NOT covered by any specification.  So any saml client has to be compatible with OpenSaml.  There is not right or wrong in this case.  If you do not like the results than modify OpenSaml.

Exclusively using transformer factory com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl gives the expected output.
